# Opencart 2.3.0 помощь

Tags: opencart

Подскажите сайты, где можно изучить, как и что настраивать на opencart. Конкретно изменение шапки, настройка элементов. Может кто то знает ютуб каналы, где рассказывается про это всё.  У меня 2.3.0 версия. Спасибо.

Comment: или может у вас есть сайт, где бесплатные опенкарт 2.3.0 шаблоны можно повыбирать. (нормальные шаблоны)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь, может что подойдет:
[№1](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2120)
[№2](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2170)
[№3](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2127)

Еще здесь: [+1](https://weburoki.pro/sborka-luchshih-urokov-po-opencart)

В большинстве случаев, лучшие шаблоны 
  [тут](https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/free-templates/#gref)

Уроки на 
  [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyTYnGUFuw0&list=PLrCWaCSWzvLG4GPtw7h0QfeJtFjvmVq1_)

Comment: спасибо за помощь!