# Есть какие-то обучалки по opencart?

Tags: opencart

Как все там устроенно какой файл за что отвечает. В интеренете не нашел ничего полезного. Как изменять внешний вид, модключать модули и прочее

Comment: `В интеренете не нашел ничего полезного` фантастику глаголете.

Comment: может не так я искал

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661541/opencart-2-3-0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Офф.сайт](https://www.opencart.com/)

[Документация](https://docs.ocstore.com/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[Книги](http://docs.opencart.com/#additional-reading)

[Офф.форум](https://forum.opencart.com/)

[Форум рус.](https://opencartforum.com/)

[YouTube серия уроков](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyTYnGUFuw0&list=PLrCWaCSWzvLG4GPtw7h0QfeJtFjvmVq1_)

[Уроки OpenCart](https://weburoki.pro/sborka-luchshih-urokov-po-opencart)

[Статьи по OpenCart](https://webformyself.com/category/cms-2/opencart-cms-2/)

[Как создать интернет-магазин на OpenCart: пошаговая инструкция](https://texterra.ru/blog/kak-sozdat-internet-magazin-na-opencart-poshagovaya-instruktsiya.html)

А так Google в [помощь](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=opencart%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)